# Find a unique element in a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I found lot's of documentation about lists in Python. But I did not find an answer for the following case:

I have a list like this: `[False, False, False, VARIABLE, False, False]`.

Does exist a way in order to get the VARIABLE value (is an integer) without a for loop on each element and using list comprehension? A kind of "which", in order to say: Select items in the list WHICH are not False.

Important point, the VARIABLE will always be unique in the list. There is no possibility to have two VARIABLE in the list.

**EDIT**

**In my case, the solution given by @AChampion is the best one. Thank you for this tip. I had to get the value of VARIABLE, which is exactly what I have with your solution.**

Comment: List comprehensions are the most pythonic way I can think of, for this. Also, what if the `__bool__` of `VARIABLE` evaluates to `False`?

Comment: List comprehensions also use `for` loops.

Comment: list comprehensions != always most pythonic.  In fact some list comprehensions are not pythonic at all.

Comment: False is equivalent to 0 so you can `sum(my_list)`

Comment: the name of the function you are looking for is : filter.

Comment: VARIABLE is an integer in each cases possible, it can not be False in my algorithm. 

Ok so, I have to use something like `[i != False for i in List]` and then extract the True?

Comment: Thank you for these answers, I'll see about filter and sum function. Thanks @AChampion and Imsteffan for these propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) ([`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python3) if the integer is non-zero

```
>>> x = [False, False, False, 10, False, False]
>>> reduce(lambda i,j:i or j, x)
10
```

You can use a generator expression also here

```
>>> x = [False, False, False, 10, False, False]
>>> (i for i in x if i!=False).next()
10
```

Also check the package [`first`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/first)

```
>>> from first import first
>>> first([False, False, False, 10, False, False])
10
```

Comment: reduce on `[False, 0, False]` returns `False` not 0 (`reduce` is in `functools` for python3)

Comment: @AChampion Corrected the statement. Will add additional technique in a moment